# Superset oauth ssl certificate validation failure

Tags: apache-superset

We are trying to integrate OAUTH in superset.Superset installation is currently not secure and running on Http, however, SSO end points are SSL enabled. We are getting the error -

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sso.company.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /platform-sso-server/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)')))
```

Is there a way to disable the SSL certificate verification.
I have tried adding below lines in superset_config.py, but it didn't help.

```
import ssl
ssl.SSLContext.verify_mode =ssl.VerifyMode.CERT_NONE
```

I am on superset 1.3.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

could try put these code in **supserset_config.py**

```
import ssl
try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Didn't change anything for me. But I have another error: `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1013: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'trino'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings`.